# Creating a new String in C for use in a large library (GLib) without using fprintf

Tags: c, string, error-handling, glib

(While this question may seem specific to GLib or error handling at first, you don't really need to know anything about those to answer my question.)

I'm attempting to use [g_set_error](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html#g-set-error) from GLib to handle my deleting file error correctly. I'm not super great with C, but my gut told me doing something like the following might be okay (3rd line):

```
void file_delete(const gchar *name) {
    if (remove(name) != 0) {
        gchar *errmsg = ("Error deleting file %s: %s.", name, strerror(errno));
        g_set_error(NULL, SDS_ERROR, 0, errmsg);
    }
    else {
        //log file <name> deleted
    }
}
```

Is it okay to create a new String this way? Or should I split `errmsg` into 3 separate Strings and concatenate them? Or some other method?

Comment: C++ != C.  You appear to be talking about the latter.  Tags edited.

Comment: Where you read about such syntax `gchar * errmsg = ("...."...)`? This is not function call with parameters.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, isn't creating a String in C and C++ pretty much the same thing? Someone with decent knowledge of either could probably pretty easily answer this question for me. No reason to exclude a very large group of people from answering this question. Tags edited back.

Comment: @i486, Well, I know you can call `printf(char*)`, so I figured I could extract the `char*` that you would find in a `printf` call and assign it directly to a `char*`. This is why I mentioned that my "gut" felt like this was a possibility and what the entire question revolves around.

Comment: In C++, what you mean by "string" is not even necessarily the same as what you mean in C context.  The ways one would prefer to approach the problem in C++ do not work in C, and C++ aficionados frown on the ways you would approach it in C (and on raw C strings in general).

Comment: @CommanderCody You'll need something like `sprintf()` rather.

Comment: Since you're using GLib already, might as well use their string utility methods, such as [`g_strdup_printf`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf).

Comment: You should be mindful of the string returned by `strerror` - Though often it is a static string -  error strings produced by `strerror` may be specific to each system and library implementation. also consider `g_strerror`

Comment: Not sure why the question is being downvoted. I did attempt to find the answer on my own, I'm fairly certain the question is clear, and other people might come accross it and find it useful in the future. Please upvote at least back to zero so it will show up when someone like myself needs help.

Comment: @CommanderCody No! It's not! You would tackle this situation completely differently in C and C++ and remember: C and C++ are different languages even though they share some similarities. Please pick one. I'm removing the C++ tag once again as you seem to write C instead of C++ code.

Comment: @FUZxxl I did pick one! My question relates to C... the title is in C, my program is in C. I included C++ tag to get the most visibility possible.

Comment: And that's against the rules. Do not include irrelevant tags. That's tag spamming.

Comment: noted. I should clarify that it was intended to get the most visibility to people who can answer the question, which is what tags are for. I still find it hard to believe the question itself has a -4. I feel like it is being unfairly downgraded due to a perceived injustice involving c and c++. Should I delete the question?

Comment: or maybe instead of deleting it, someone could propose a way of improving the question? or pointing out its flaws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't create a string like that, that would return the result of `strerror(errno)`.

In my opinion, it would be best to concatenate multiple strings together.

However, you could instead do this:

```
gchar *errmsg = malloc(256); // change this size as needed
snprintf(255, errmsg, "Error deleting file %s: %s.", name, strerror(errno));
```

If you would prefer format strings, but don't forget to `free(errmsg)`.

**UPDATE**

Also, as @Kninnug said in the comments of the question:

> Since you're using GLib already, might as well use their string utility methods, such as g_strdup_printf

Comment: Thanks, `snprintf` and `sprintf` are exactly what I was looking for. I may take your suggestion and just concatenate everything instead though.

Comment: For anyone that comes across this question and is using GLib, please use Kninnug's comment from the question as the answer. @NunzioTocci, can you maybe add that to the answer itself?

Comment: Good idea, thank you @Kninnug and CommanderCody. Answer updated.